# I have a class for creating objects from a database row. How to design a class to perform functions on all rows e.g. counts on db table

Tags: design-patterns, php, class-design

Say I have a database for storing cars data. Each row is essentially a car and I've a class that takes a row of the data and builds my car object.

I now want to build a dashboard that can tell me all the types of cars e.g.

```
Type        Amount
BMW           12
Ford          7
```

I'm trying to figure out how best to design the functionality. My thoughts so far have been:

- Static function call in a generic functions class. Does a count on
  the table. Not exactly an OOP approach so I'd prefer not to do this.
- Create a class for counting cars. Not sure if this is too
  specific a case to warrant it's own class.
- A database interface class for cars table. Perform general
  functions, counts, bulk updates etc. Should be static?
- A counter interface class? I'm not too clear on how to build this, it's something I've kind of gleaned from reading about interfaces and decoupling?

Those are the thoughts I had. What are the suggested ways to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. Which you are going to use depends on your preferences and whether you are having an underlaying `framework` or `CMS` which uses a certain way. In case you are using a `framework` or similiar check their coding guidelines.

Despite that I am aware of following options:

- `DBAL` that provides `functions` like `count($table)`.
- `Model` that provides `functions` like `count`. Further the model provides functions like `get(id)` and `set(...$args)`
- A `RepositoryClass` that supports `CRUD` for it's model and general `methods` used to interact with the database. For each `Model` you have a `RepositoryClass`.
- A `ListClass` that you can use with `count()`. Similiar to `RepositoryClass`. However, the ListClass contains actually a list while the RepositoryClass returns objects or e.g. the amount of cars in your database.

I prefer the usage of either a `ListClass` and or `RepositoryClass`. In the following example we have a `CarRepository` having a method to retrieve every available brand. The method `findCarBrands` returns the class `CarBrandList` which contains a list with models of type `CarBrand`. As it is a list we can iterate through it and access each brand. The `CarBrand`-Model has a method to get the total amount of available cars per brand. You may ask yourself where is the returned value of `getTotalCars` determined. This is done in the repository class when we iterate through the `sql` `resultSet` or in the `sql statement itself`.

```
<?php
     /** @var CarBrandList $carBrands*/
     $carBrands = $carRepository->findCarBrands();

     /** @var CarBrand $carBrand*/
     foreach ($carBrands as $carBrand)
     {
          echo $carBrand->getName() . ' | ' . $carBrand()->getTotalCars() . '<br/>';
     }
```